# Is there any symbol for intersects?

Tags: notation

Given two polygons $A$ and $B$ the intersection of them is represented by the notation $A \cap B$ that returns a geometry (more precisely the set of intersecting points) resulting from the intersection operation.

Is there any symbol for intersects (a boolean function that returns 0 (false) or 1 (true) if $A$ intersects $B$) ?

Otherwise, what would be a good notation for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any specific notation for this.

But what about

> $$A\cap B\ne \emptyset$$

This statement is true if $A$ and $B$ have any overlap, false otherwise.

This returns true for *any* overlap, including edges and vertices. If you want to exclude those, use the [notation for the interior of the polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_of_a_set), $\operatorname{int}(A)\cap\operatorname{int}(B)\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: I'm using that at this moment with the Iverson brackets notation $[A \cap B \neq \emptyset]+\dots$, but I asked around and people never heard about the Iverson Brackets. I'm probably going to create a boolean function with this condition, now I'm looking for a symbol or name more compact than "intersects"! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function of a set $S$ is $$\chi_S(x) = \begin{cases}1,& x\in S\\0,& x\notin S\end{cases}.$$
So what you're looking for is $$\sup_{x\in\mathcal U}\chi_{A\cap B}(x),$$
where $\mathcal U$ is our universal set (i.e. $A,B\subset\mathcal U$).

Comment: That is function that tells if a given point is in the intersection. I think the OP wants a statement that says whether or not $A$ and $B$ intersect at all.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ do not intersect $\iff \chi_{A\cap B} \equiv 0$

Answer (score 0):

It's a little awkward, but perhaps you could use $\not\perp$, because, according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) Wikipedia page:

> the notation $a \perp b$ is sometimes used to indicate that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime

a usage which could be extended to a general lattice (unless the symbol $\bot$ was already in use to denote the bottom element, which would not be a problem in this case).

The notation (for the case of coprime integers) seems to have been invented by Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics* (2nd edition, 1989), section 4.5.